# Best way to compare two JSON files in Java

Tags: java, json, comparison

How would you suggest this task is approached?

The challenge as i see it is in presenting diff information intelligently. Before i go reinventing the wheel, is there an accepted approach of how such a comparison should be handled?

Comment: In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50969020/1426227) you will find a solution with Jackson/Gson and Guava.

Comment: Json Compare [Json-Compare](https://github.com/fslev/json-compare)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try the [XStream's architecture, handling of JSON mappings](http://x-stream.github.io/json-tutorial.html)

Also, take a look at this post: [Comparing two XML files & generating a third with XMLDiff in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590214/comparing-two-xml-files-generating-a-third-with-xmldiff-in-c). It's in C# but the logic is the same.

Answer (score 33):

I recommend the [zjsonpatch](https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/zjsonpatch) library, which presents the diff information in accordance with [RFC 6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) (JSON Patch).  You can use it with Jackson:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.{ObjectMapper, JsonNode}
JsonNode beforeNode = jacksonObjectMapper.readTree(beforeJsonString);
JsonNode afterNode = jacksonObjectMapper.readTree(afterJsonString);

import com.flipkart.zjsonpatch.JsonDiff
JsonNode patch = JsonDiff.asJson(beforeNode, afterNode);
String diffs = patch.toString();
```

This library is better than [fge-json-patch](https://github.com/fge/json-patch) (which was mentioned in another answer) because it can detect items being inserted/removed from arrays.  Fge-json-patch cannot handle that (if an item is inserted into the middle of an array, it will think that item and every item after that was changed since they are all shifted over by one).

Comment: This only compares the structure of the json documents.

Comment: Its comparing both keys and values. How to make it only for keys ?

Comment: The code didn't work for me. You probably need to make a new `ObjectMapper` first:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode beforeNode = jacksonObjectMapper.readTree(beforeJsonString);
JsonNode afterNode = jacksonObjectMapper.readTree(afterJsonString);
JsonNode patch = JsonDiff.asJson(beforeNode, afterNode);
String diffs = patch.toString();
```

Answer (score 17):

I've done good experience with [JSONAssert](https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert).

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONAssert;
import org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONCompareMode;

... 
@Test
public void myTest() {
  String expectedJson = FileUtils.readFileToString("/expectedFile");
  String actualJson = FileUtils.readFileToString("/actualFile");
  JSONAssert.assertEquals(expectedJson, actualJson, JSONCompareMode.STRICT);
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the only library I could find that gives you the option to ignore the order of items in lists.

Comment: This did not work as advertised and when I emailed them, the email address was no longer valid. Abandonware??

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62048635/finding-json-diff-fails-using-jsonassert

Answer (score 15):

The easiest way to compare json strings is using `JSONCompare` from [JSONAssert](https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert) library. The advantage is, it's not limited to structure only and can compare values if you wish:

```
JSONCompareResult result = 
     JSONCompare.compareJSON(json1, json2, JSONCompareMode.STRICT);
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

which will output something like:

```
Expected: VALUE1
     got: VALUE2
 ; field1.field2
```

Comment: i am getting compile time error as:  The type org.json.JSONArray cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Comment: A general rule, if u wanna use a lib, include all its dependencies or use maven to get the dependencies automatically.

Comment: This did not work as advertised and when I emailed them, the email address was no longer valid. Abandonware??

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62048635/finding-json-diff-fails-using-jsonassert

Answer (score 13):

This only addresses equality, not differences.

---

With Jackson.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

JsonNode tree1 = mapper.readTree(jsonInput1);
JsonNode tree2 = mapper.readTree(jsonInput2);

boolean areTheyEqual = tree1.equals(tree2);
```

From [the JavaDoc for JsonNode.equals](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#equals(java.lang.Object)):

> Equality for node objects is defined as full (deep) value equality. This means that it is possible to compare complete JSON trees for equality by comparing equality of root nodes.

Comment: `mapper.readTree` do not works if json fields has different order.

Comment: And only compares the structure of the json documents.

Comment: Its comparing both keys and values. How to make it only for keys ?

Comment: @EanV and also Cherry not true. it compares the values and even if members are out of order..

Comment: @Cherry json fields _can_ have a different order. But two *list elements* are only compared as equal if they have the same values in the exact same order.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and ended up writing my own library:

https://github.com/algesten/jsondiff

It does both diffing/patching.

Diffs are JSON-objects themselves and have a simple syntax for object merge/replace and array insert/replace.

Example:

```
original
{
   a: { b: 42 }
}

patch
{
  "~a": { c: 43 }
}
```

The `~` indicates an object merge.

```
result
{
   a: { b: 42, c: 43 }
}
```

Comment: Limited to the structure of the documents only.

Comment: no. it compares values too. but I don't recommend using it since I ran into hard solved edge cases and lost interest.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below dependancy to compare Json with STRICT,LENIENT,IGNORE_ORDER etc.

```html
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

```java
  public static boolean isTwoJsonEquals(JSONObject firstObj,JSONObject secondObj, JSONCompareMode compareMode){
    try {
      JSONCompareResult result = JSONCompare.compareJSON(firstObj, secondObj, compareMode);

      return result.passed();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

### json-lib

What I would do is parse the json data using [json-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/). This will result in regular java objects which you can compare using the equals methods. This is only valid though **assuming** the guys from json-lib properly implemented the equals method, but that you can easily test.

Answer (score 1):

For people who are already using **Jackson**, I recommend [**json-patch**](https://github.com/fge/json-patch)

```
final JsonNode patchNode = JsonDiff.asJson(firstNode, secondNode);
System.out.println("Diff=" + m.writeValueAsString(patchNode));
```

Comment: I went to their site and find it is licensed under LGPLv3. correct me if I am mistaken but isn't LGPL very restrictive for corporations to use?

Answer (score 0):

In case if want to compare two JSON Ignoring the order of elements/object, see if this [library](https://github.com/nareshsaw5/common-json-diff) helps you.

Usage:

```
List<Diff> diff = new DnjsonDiff().getDiff(String left, String right)
Left =[{"name":"Bob","businessKey":"4444"},{"name":"John","businessKey":"5555"}]
Right = [{"name":"Bob","businessKey":"6666"},{"name":"John", "businessKey":"4444"}]

Diff:

[
    {
        "op": "replace",
        "configuredValue": "John",
        "intendedValue": "Bob",
        "businessKey": "4444"
    },
    {
        "op": "remove",
        "configuredValue": null,
        "intendedValue": "{\"name\":\"John\",\"businessKey\":\"5555\"}",
        "businessKey": "5555"
    },
    {
        "op": "add",
        "configuredValue": "{\"name\":\"Bob\",\"businessKey\":\"6666\"}",
        "intendedValue": null,
        "businessKey": "null"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Google's Guava library** for comparison. Check this answer which has detailed explanation on how to use this.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50969020/17762303

Answer (score 0):

Junit5 already supports comparing two json object with also content check.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json1 = {"key" : "value"}; // from file
String json2 = {"key" : "value"};

Assertions.assertEquals(mapper.readTree(json1), mapper.readTree(json2));
```