# Flatten a json structure in java

Tags: json, jsonpath

So I'm having a minor issue, thinking of what is the easiest way to do this.
Basically I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "users": {
    "userId1": {
      "externalUser.userId": "uid1",
      "externalUser.profileId": "pid1"
    }
  },
  "externalAccount.id": "acid1"
}
```

And I want to convert it to a map looking like this:

```
"externalAccount.id", "acid1"
"users.userId1.externalUser.userId", "uid1"
"users.userId1.externalUser.profileId", "pid1"
```

And of course the conversion has to work both ways. 
I was thinking of finding some way to use jackson to do that, because I know we can do it with jsonpath but I don't know how.

Comment: `Flatten a json structure in java`. I guess it's Java....

Comment: The solution I described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50969020/1426227) could be part of the solution.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: https://github.com/wnameless/json-flattener