# Compare two xml files

Tags: c#, xml, compare

I want to compare two xml files with the same structure. I want to know exactly what are  difference in each nodes.

What is the best way to do this ?

Comment: Do you always have the same elements/objects in your files and only their parametervalues change or does the whole thing change?

Comment: Yes always the same element but not always the same count. Element repeated etc

Comment: Does this help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590214/comparing-two-xml-files-generating-a-third-with-xmldiff-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

There is no silver bullet for this type question, it depends on the structure and size of your xml file. If it is short and with fewer properties and attribute, and diff/merge tool is OK for this task. If it is in a complex structure, you need write program to parse and compare it.

Answer (score 0):

Like @gzh said, there is no silver bullet.

You could try `Oxygen XML Diff Files` program, it comes with `OxygenXML Developer`. (I am not affiliated with Oxygen XML). I believe other XML tools have similar functionality.

Or, you could try `XSLT`. But there is a significant learning curve with `XSLT`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I prefer a text-based comparison, so I run a formatter on both XML files and compare them using a tool like Eclipse or Winmerge.

The Eclipse formatter seems to work fine with XML files (but not with HTML or JSF files). Alternatively, the "pretty print" plugin of Notepad++ does a good job formatting the files (see [this StackOverflow question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961217/how-to-format-xml-in-notepad).